# Como fazer o programa parar em cada printf()?

Tags: c, scanf, printf

Gostaria de fazer o usuário digitar um `printf()` por vez, sendo o "Nome, RG e Email" porém assim que digito o nome, ele executa todo o resto e acaba o programa, como faço ele parar nos próximos `printf()` para o usuário?

```
int main () {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");

    int opcao, tipoPessoa, nomePessoa, rgPessoa, emailPessoa;

    printf("Bem Vindo ! \n O que deseja fazer ? \n 1 - Se cadastrar \n 2 - Reservar um lugar \n");
    scanf("%d",&opcao);

    if (opcao == 1){
        printf("Você é: \n 1 - Professor \n 2 - Aluno \n 3 - Convidado \n 4 - Portador de necessidade especial \n");
        scanf("%d", &tipoPessoa);
        switch(tipoPessoa){
            case 1: printf("Informe seu nome completo: ");
                    scanf("%d", &nomePessoa);
                    printf("Informe seu RG: ");
                    scanf("%d", &rgPessoa);
                    printf("Informe seu E-mail: ");
                    scanf("%d", &emailPessoa);

        }       
    }

}
```

Comment: A primeira coisa, por que quer que tudo seja um inteiro? O erro pode ser este, porque não vejo nada que possa causar o problema descrito, na verdade, nem assim é pra dar esse problema.

Comment: Na verdade sou iniciante em C, talvez esse seja o problema ? qual seria a solução ?

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 2):

Quando você precisa pegar dados descritos, ou seja textos, precisa guardar isto em sequências de caracteres, então precisa criar um vetor de `char` com tamanho suficiente para a quantidade de caracteres que vai armazenar mais 1 caracteres que será o terminador. Idealmente deveria limitar a entrada de dados para esta quantidade conforme [formatação do `scanf()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf). O código ainda não é o ideal mas para primeiros exercícios ok. Só acho que deveria começar aprender conceitos mais básicos, uma coisa de cada vez, em ordem correta, de forma estruturada para evitar gerar cada vez mais confusão no aprendizado.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
    int opcao;
    printf("Bem Vindo ! \n O que deseja fazer ? \n 1 - Se cadastrar \n 2 - Reservar um lugar \n");
    scanf("%d", &opcao);
    if (opcao == 1) {
        int tipoPessoa;
        printf("Você é: \n 1 - Professor \n 2 - Aluno \n 3 - Convidado \n 4 - Portador de necessidade especial \n");
        scanf("%d", &tipoPessoa);
        switch(tipoPessoa) {
            case 1: {
                char nomePessoa[31], rgPessoa[10], emailPessoa[65];
                printf("Informe seu nome completo: ");
                scanf("%30s", nomePessoa);
                printf("Informe seu RG: ");
                scanf("%9s", rgPessoa);
                printf("Informe seu E-mail: ");
                scanf("%64s", emailPessoa);
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/aZ7DDQ). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/zxqzysjl-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Console/GetString.c).

Comment: são respostas como a sua que pessoas que estão começando precisam, obrigado por responder da mesma forma quando eu estava aprendendo também.